# How to use require/include in linux PHP

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, require

I recently shifted my development enviroment from windows to ubuntu. Lets say I require a file like this in windows:

```
require('core/main.php');
```

Now I want to do that same thing but I'd have to do it like this in ubuntu:

```
require('/var/www/project_folder/core/main.php');
```

I have many projects and most of them use the windows method of fetching the file, is it possible to do the same in linux like in windows? Do I have to set some link somewhere?

Comment: Note the one you mention for Ubuntu is like `/var/...`, that is, full path, whereas in windows you say `core/...` - relative path. So if you use relative paths in ubuntu, it should be fine.

Comment: That's most probably not an issue of Linux or Windows, but how your [`include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) is configured. Check your include paths on both development environments.

Comment: That seemed to be the issue. I set the include path to the project directory and relative paths are now working.
`set_include_path('/var/www/project_directory');`

Comment: You can also define relative paths based on `__DIR__`, like `require_once(__DIR__ . '/core/main.php')`.

Answer (score 0):

That's most probably not an issue of Linux or Windows, but how your [`include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) is configured. Check your include paths on both development environments.
                    – helmbert

That seemed to be the issue. I set the include path to the project directory and relative paths are now working. `set_include_path('/var/www/project_directory');`
                    – Irfan Dahir